# Start an activity from the ListView inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

I want to start an activity from the listview elements made inside a fragment. I have searched for this but didn't got any solution. I have tried everything i got from stackoverflow earlier asked questions but nothing worked and every time my app crashed.

Here is my code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_cse1_notes, container, false);
ListView sem1List = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sem1Lv);
final ArrayList<String> sem1Courses = new ArrayList<String>();
    sem1Courses.add("Applied Physics 1");
    sem1Courses.add("Applied Mathematics 1");
    sem1Courses.add("Engineering Mechanics");
    sem1Courses.add("English Language Usage Essentials");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSem1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sem1Courses);
sem1List.setAdapter(adapterSem1);
sem1List.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
final Intent intent;
switch (position){
case 0:
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), phy1Details.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
case 1:
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), appMath1Details.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
case 2:
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), engMech1Details.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
case 3:
    intent = new Intent(getActivity(), engLangUseDetails.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    break;
        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvSem1"
            />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="550dip"
            android:id="@+id/sem1Lv"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </LinearLayout>`
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log?

Comment: Please share the crashlog

Comment: I checked the log and got the solution. I didn't declared my activity in the manifest file so i was getting the exception. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
intent = new Intent(rootView.getContext(), phy1Details.class);
view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `itemClickListener` inside `onActivityCreated`.

Your activity is not initiated inside `onCreateView` yet, so you're probably experiencing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> setOnItemClickListener

on list view and start your new activity.
By clicking on any value in your list view you the will the value as well as you can start any operation with that.

See the following code: Here

> selected

variable stored the value of selected item in the list view.

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            status=true;
            String selected = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleMessage)).getText().toString();

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"selected"+selected ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            i.putExtra("place_lat", lat);
            i.putExtra("place_lng", lng);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```